# Is there any way to modify built-in shortcuts in Okular?

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts, ubuntu-14.04, okular

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 with the following okular version:

-Qt: 4.8.6
-KDE Development Platform: 4.13.3
-Okular: 0.19.3

I know that I can configure the shortcuts that are available in the Settings>Configure shortcuts. **Is there a way or a file that lets me modify the shortcuts for functions not included in that list?**.

Motivation: I want vim like scrolling for my okular. So I want to configure the basic scrolling to hjkl. But from the available menu I can only configure auto-scroll or page scroll options respectively. This has been bothering me for some time now, and is even making me consider learning the KDE framework to make this doable; apparently that would like chasing Moby Dick.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about 0.19 but in 0.24 I've created my on scheme. In "Configure Shortcuts" you can export or save the default values to a file.

~/.kde4/share/apps/okular/okularDefaultshortcuts.rc

or
~/.kde/share/apps/okular/okularDefaultshortcuts.rc

Comment: like I said in my comment, I know you can modify from the defined shortcuts from "Configure Shortcuts". However, I want to modify other builtin scrolling that works with cursor keys to hjkl. I do not think I can do that with the configure shortcuts option.

Comment: If it's only the cursor keys hjkl for scrolling in okular already supports them.

Comment: Perhaps I need to get the newer version, because it does not work in my one. I will get back to you after (if) I update.

Comment: It might be that your okular is old but is it older than 2008? Have a look at this commit. [link](https://github.com/KDE/okular/commit/1d91c234324fdef0b49384a4e701c13519b8896e)

Comment: I know its way late to be writing back, but my okular version is 0.19.3 and my KDE development platform is 4.13.3. I do not know if you have newer or older versions.